# How do I do I make an inherited immutable property mutable in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, properties

Consider that I have an interface that contains the following property

```
interface IFoo
{
    Int32 Id { get; }
}
```

Now say I want to create an IMutableFoo interface.  Logically I would think that the following was correct:

```
interface IMutableFoo: IFoo
{
    Int32 Id { set; }
}
```

My thought is that it would inherit Id and then in my child interface I'd make it settable.  To my surprise, this did not work.  Instead I get a warning letting me know that I'm in fact overriding the Id in IFoo with the Id in IMutableFoo.  I tried changing { set; } to { get; set; } with the same results.  How do I do this right?  In Java, I would simply add a setId method.  How do I do this in C#?  Thanks!

Comment: You may also want to refer to a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399503/can-you-use-the-c-sharp-new-keyword-to-expand-properties-on-an-interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-declaration of Id in the descendent interface indeed hides the one in the parent.

I use two different workarounds for this, entailing tradeoffs that I do not particularly like.

1 - Using an abstract or even a non-abstract class instead of a mutable interface.

```
interface IFoo {
    Int32 Id { get; }
}
abstract class MutableFoo: IFoo {
    public abstract Int32 Id {get; set;}
}
```

The biggest drawback is that the users of your library can no longer program to an interface.

2 - Using a method instead of a property.

```
interface IFoo {
    Int32 Id { get; }
}
interface IMutableFoo: IFoo {
    void SetId(Int32 value);
}
```

This is not ideal, because the setter is not idiomatic, and looks disconnected from the getter.

Comment: Thanks.  Ultimately, I went with an abstract class.  That's sufficient for what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing you can do other than defining a new interface with a new read/write property. This is because there is no concept of inheritance when talking about interfaces; rather, an interface such as `IMutableFoo` is a promise that its implementers will also implement the interface `IFoo`. Both interfaces, however, were defined independently and remain independent.

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) contains the phrase *"interfaces can inherit other interfaces"*, but this is IMHO misleading as there is no inheritance going on here. The "derived" interface simply describes a larger set of members that have to be implemented than the "base" interface.

Implementers of an interface such as `IMutableFoo` can provide the semantics you target with no problem by explicitly implementing `IFoo` and sharing code between the getters of `IMutableFoo.Id` and `IFoo.Id`:

```
class Foo : IMutableFoo {
    // IFoo is implemented explicitly
    // "this" is of type Foo, and since IMutableFoo is implemented
    // implicitly below, this.Id accesses the Id declared in IMutableFoo
    Int32 IFoo.Id { get { return this.Id; } }

    // IMutableFoo is implemented implicitly
    // It could also be implemented explicitly, but the body of the
    // IFoo.Id getter would need to change ("this" would no longer work)
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately there is no mechanism that *forces* implementers to do this, but some good documentation can go a long way here -- even more so if the relationship between `IFoo` and `IMutableFoo` is intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
  public interface IFoo
    {
        Int32 Id { get; }
    }

   public interface IFooMu : IFoo
    {
        new Int32 Id { get; set; }
    }  

    class Foo : IFooMu
    {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge difference between saying a property is "immutable", versus saying it is "read-only".  A object property which is "immutable" is one that will never ever change, for any reason, as long as the object in question exists.  By contrast a "read-only" property is one which cannot be changed using a property setter, but might potentially be changed via other means.

Your question seems to be about how to have an object support both read-only and read-write interfaces in sensible fashion; Keith Nicholas' answer illustrates the proper method.  Note that if one uses explicit interface implementation, or if one writes the class in vb.net rather than c#, it will be necessary to have separate implementations of both IFooMu.Id and IFoo.Id; that is an annoying requirement imposed by .net, but c# allows one public property to at as implicit definition for read-only, read-write, and write-only properties.